# PHP get result in same rows if month is same

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I  am facing an issue to get result in same row if the month is same. I am using UNION ALL in query. Can anyone please advise how to use the query to get result as per my requirement.

I am using below code:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(amount) AS amount,
   DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate,'%M %Y') as rcv,
   NULL AS recovery 
FROM `advertisercv` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate, '%M %Y')
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
   NULL,
   DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') AS rcv,
   SUM(amount) 
FROM `paymentsrec` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y') 
ORDER BY rcv
```

[image: sample data]

Comment: Group by month. Then, you can use coalesce to get the first non-null value for a column.

Comment: whats coalesce ?

Comment: Have you considered using a search engine for "mysql coalesce"?

Comment: coalesce not working

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
SELECT
  SUM(amount) as amount,
  DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate,'%M %Y') as rcv,
  null as recovery 
FROM `advertisercv` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate, '%M %Y')
UNION all 
SELECT 
  null,
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') as rcv,
  SUM(amount) 
FROM `paymentsrec`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y') 
order by rcv
```

To make this easier to work with, I strongly suggest giving the columns the same name for each subselect:

```
SELECT
  SUM(amount) as amount,
  DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate,'%M %Y') as rcv,
  null as recovery 
FROM `advertisercv` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate, '%M %Y')
UNION all 
SELECT 
  null as amount,
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') as rcv,
  SUM(amount) as recovery
FROM `paymentsrec`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y') 
order by rcv
```

Now you can see that you will get multiple rows containing amount,rcv,recovery. You want those rows grouped by rcv:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(amount) as amount,
    DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate,'%M %Y') as rcv,
    null as recovery 
  FROM `advertisercv` 
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate, '%M %Y')
  UNION all 
  SELECT 
    null as amount,
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') as rcv,
    SUM(amount) as recovery
  FROM `paymentsrec`
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y') 
  order by rcv
) GROUP BY rcv
```

But, * is not a group operator. What do we do when we have multiple rows with the same rcv? You can sum them. You can get the max or min. The way you phrased the question, it looks like you want coalesce - the first non-null value.

```
SELECT
  rcv,
  COALESCE(amount) as amount,
  COALESCE(recover) as recovery
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(amount) as amount,
    DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate,'%M %Y') as rcv,
    null as recovery 
  FROM `advertisercv` 
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rcvdate, '%M %Y')
  UNION all 
  SELECT 
    null as amount,
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %Y') as rcv,
    SUM(amount) as recovery
  FROM `paymentsrec`
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y') 
  order by rcv
) GROUP BY rcv
```

Now, you will get one row per rcv value and both amount and recovery will contain the first non-null value per rcv value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inconvenience، but still not getting the result :(